# Python Popen, broken pipe erro

Tags: python, libsvm

Currently I'm using libsvm, with a library (easy.py and grid.py[1]) written in Python. I have "[Errono32]: Broken pipe ". I don't know python but after a while googling for the error, I know it comes from reading/writing files. Thus I copied all the I/O file access code here, I don't know which one of them cause this problem.. Hope you can help me.

Fraction 1:

```
class LocalWorker(Worker):
    def run_one(self,c,g):
        cmdline = self.get_cmd(c,g)
        result = Popen(cmdline,shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,stdin=PIPE).stdout
        for line in result.readlines():
            if str(line).find('Cross') != -1:
                return float(line.split()[-1][0:-1])
```

Fraction 2:

```
class SSHWorker(Worker):
    def __init__(self,name,job_queue,result_queue,host,options):
        Worker.__init__(self,name,job_queue,result_queue,options)
        self.host = host
        self.cwd = os.getcwd()
    def run_one(self,c,g):
        cmdline = 'ssh -x -t -t {0} "cd {1}; {2}"'.format\
            (self.host,self.cwd,self.get_cmd(c,g))
        result = Popen(cmdline,shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,stdin=PIPE).stdout
        for line in result.readlines():
            if str(line).find('Cross') != -1:
                return float(line.split()[-1][0:-1])
```

Fraction 3:

```
if options.gnuplot_pathname:
    gnuplot = Popen(options.gnuplot_pathname,stdin = PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE).stdin
else:
    gnuplot = None
```

I'm using Mac os 10.9, python 2.7.5, I have two computer, running on same macos and python version, but the one can run fine without error, one runs with broken pipe error.

If you have any suggestion, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Broken pipe happens in an attempt to write to a closed pipe. Apparently you only write to gnuplot. It looks like on one of your system gnuplot just fails to start. From the  information available I can't help more.